# Can I init a derived dataclass using an instance of its base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simply, if I have base class:

```
@dataclass
class Base:
  foo: int
  bar: int
```

and derived class:

```
@dataclass
class Derived(Base):
  baz: int
```

I want to do this:

```
base = Base(1, 2)
derived = Derived(base, 3)
```

But this would try to assign `base` to `derived.foo`. Is there a way to accomplish this in such a way that I don't have to iterate over each field?  I could for example serialize `base` to json, add the additional field, then deserialize to `derived` but that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Write your own `__init__`. Or better, write an alternative constructor, `from_base(base,  baz)`

Comment: Even with my own init, I would have to (afaik)  manually go through each field, which I'm trying to avoid; I was hoping a class could be deconstructed like an array, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Just do it. You can do it dynamically if you really must, playing around with the `__dict__` but you have to know what you are doing, and in any case, it just makes your code more complex for essentially zero benefit.

Comment: Why do you need to make the `Base` instance in the first place? Constructing one only to deconstruct it for the purpose of making a child instance seems kind of pointless.

Comment: @wim Indeed that does work! If you can answer I will accept. I didn't know that the dataclass constructor by default accepts a dict - thanks for the help (especially without criticism asking 'but why...' :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpack the fields of one instance when creating another:

```
>>> from dataclasses import asdict
>>> Derived(**asdict(base), baz=3)  # by keyword
Derived(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
>>> Derived(*asdict(base).values(), 3)  # positional
Derived(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
```

Note that using `asdict` makes a deep-copy, so that there won't be any references accidentally shared.